# SSIS Datetime conversion issue

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have loaded the CSV to the DB using SSIS. I found some conversion error i.e. yyyy-mm-dd it was loaded correctly till 2022-05-31 then for the next month it started loading like 2022-06-01 ( yyyy-dd-mm) format. Can you please guide me how to fix this issue?

I have used the datatype as datetime and would like to have it in the  format yyyy-mm-dd

in the raw file the format is mm/dd/yyyy

Comment: `datetime` is not stored in a format like `yyyy-mm-dd` - that is just how tools like SSMS present it to you. If your dates are `m/d/y` then apply an explicit conversion style (`CONVERT(datetime, value, 101)`) so that they don't get interpreted incorrectly. We can't tell you _exactly_ how because we can't see your code. Better yet would be to fix the source so that raw files are produced with unambiguous formats like `yyyymmdd`.

Comment: Prior to load, you can SET DATEFORMAT MDY

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.